# CXF SOAP Client outbound message has empty body

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client

I had generated a set of classes using WSDL2Java and had built a testing client to try invoke the SOAP Service.

The classes are generated, but when I call the web service, i notice that the `body` of the outbound message is empty.

The following is some info on the stuff i got:

**The Ant script**

```
<target depends="clear-cxf-client-src" name="cxf-wsdl-java">
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
         <arg value="-client"/>
         <arg value="-d"/>
         <arg value="${src.dir}"/>
         <arg value="-exsh"/>
         <arg value="true"/>             
         <arg value="-autoNameResolution"/>
         <arg value="-wsdlLocation"/>
         <arg value="${wsdl.url}"/>
         <arg value="${wsdl.url}"/>              
         <classpath>
            <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
   </target>
```

**The client code**

```
URL wsdlURL = Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) { 
    File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
    try {
        if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
            wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
        } else {
            wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Service service = new Service();
ReqServicePortType port = service.getReqServicePort();

String endpoint = "http://server:port/<path to end point>";
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint); 
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username"); 
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password"); 
provider.getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled", "true");

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
loggingInInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
loggingOutInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
client.getInInterceptors().add(loggingInInterceptor);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);

HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
CustomHeader header= new CustomHeader();
//setting header value....      
header.setTimestamp(sdf.format(new Date()));

Holder<CustomHeader> headers = new Holder<CustomHeader>(header);

ReqDoc reqDoc = new ReqDoc();
//setting reqDoc value...
reqDoc.setTranxId("5");

ProcessReq req = new ProcessReq();
req.setInput(reqDoc);           

ProcessReqResponse response = port.processReq(req, headers);

RespDoc respDoc = null;
if(response != null){
    respDoc = response.getOutput();
}

String msgCode = "";
String msgDesc = "";
if(respDoc != null){
    msgCode = respDoc.getMsgCode();
    msgDesc = respDoc.getMsgDesc();
}

System.out.println("msgCode: " + msgCode);
System.out.println("msgDesc: " + msgDesc);
```

**The outbound message log**

```
INFO: Outbound Message
--------------------------- ID: 1 Address: http://server:port/<path to service> Encoding: UTF-8 Http-Method: POST Content-Type: text/xml Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Authorization=[Basic 12341323232323=], SOAPAction=["Service_Binder_processReq"]} Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <soap:Header>
    <header xmlns:ns3="http://<my package>" xmlns:ns2="http://<my schema>" xmlns="http://<my schema>">
      <timestamp>20150525115746</timestamp>
    </header>   </soap:Header>   <soap:Body/> </soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see i'd tried setting chuking to `false` but it's still the same.

Any comments or idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was found that this happens when you run the generated client class without referencing the CXF Lib jar files. After adding them into the classpath, the body of the message is then generated.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. But in my case I don't use CXF, I am using JAXB client. Do you have any idea what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the soap body was empty due to different versions of cxf jars on the classpath. I am using camel-cxf 2.5.3 which depends on cxf version 3.0.6. I included mistakenly the cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty 3.1.1 version in my gradle script which added the 3.1.1 cxf-core and that caused the empty soap body issue. By putting the version 3.0.6 for cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty fixed the issue and now the body is correctly populated.